# ¿Cómo usar correctamente AsyncTask en Android?

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de usar el `AsyncTask` para ejecutar un hilo en `segundo plano`, que es un  `timer` que `reinicia cada 20 segundos`, aqui esta mi codigo pero no logro hacerlo funcionar correctamente, alguien me puede decir cual es mi error?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Boolean  statusKeyboard = false;
private EditText mTextoEditor1;
private Button mBotonSend;
private TextView mDumpTextView;
private MiTareaAsincrona tarea1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

    mBotonSend = findViewById(R.id.bt2_SendButton);
    mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1_ReadValues);
    mTextoEditor1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1_WriteValues);

    mBotonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = mTextoEditor1.getText().toString();
            if (mTextoEditor1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Por favar Ingresar al texto...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {                                
                mDumpTextView.append( message + "\r\n" );
            }
            mTextoEditor1.setText("");
        }
    });

    tarea1 = new MiTareaAsincrona();
    tarea1.execute();
}

private class MiTareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        setupTimer(20);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Timer finalizado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() { }
}

private void setupTimer(Integer milisegundos) {
    new CountDownTimer( milisegundos, 1000 ) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //mDumpTextView.setText( "seconds: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000 );
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mDumpTextView.setText( "done!" );
            start();
        }
    }.start();
  }
}
```

Aquí el error que aparece en el log:

```
04-26 12:17:42.316 31649-31668/com.wsalas.myicontest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.wsalas.myicontest, PID: 31649
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
    at com.wsalas.myicontest.MainActivity$2.<init>(MainActivity.java:73)
    at com.wsalas.myicontest.MainActivity.setupTimer(MainActivity.java:73)
    at com.wsalas.myicontest.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:19)
    at com.wsalas.myicontest.MainActivity$MiTareaAsincrona.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
    at com.wsalas.myicontest.MainActivity$MiTareaAsincrona.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-26 12:17:42.626 1441-2116/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 288x288
04-26 12:17:42.906 1441-2210/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
04-26 12:17:42.956 31649-31649/com.wsalas.myicontest E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
04-26 12:17:44.036 31689-31689/? E/android_hardware_fm: FM : loading QCOMM FM-JNI
```

Comment: algún error se muestra en el LogCat, por lo que comentas tal vez no es necesario un Asynctask

Comment: Trato de aprender de cómo usar correctamente un `Asynctask`, en este caso necesito que el `timer corra en forma independiente en otro hilo`, solo por comodidad he colocado un timer en reemplazo de un código el cual se comporta como un timer pero su código es muy grande como para colocarlo en el foro

Answer (score 0):

No se puede manejar las vistas (UI) desde un hilo que no sea el principal, 
te recomendaría utilzar el siguiente código, cada que quieras actualizar las vistas desde otro hilo

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // runs on UI thread
    }
});
```

Comment: En que parte de código  coloco el `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu código, la única parte donde se modifica el UI desde un hilo secundario es dentro del método setupTimer en      mDumpTextView.setText( "done!" );.  Eso debe de estar dentro del código que puse